# Use the Chrome Windows API to close windows in a set order from an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window, es6-promise

In my Chrome extension, I am using a background page to close all the current windows and open a new one. However, I need to close a specific window (one that is created by the extension earlier) last, so that it will be reopened first if Ctrl+Shift+T is pressed. I have tried using promises to close it after closing the others, but when I press Ctrl+Shift+T, an older window always gets reopened first. The code I am using is:

```
//closeLast is the id of the window that needs to be closed last

//promise version of chrome.windows.remove
function removeWindow(windowId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        chrome.windows.remove(windowId, resolve);
    });
}

//closes all windows but one
function closeOthers(newWindow){
    chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows){
        let promises = [];

        windows.forEach(function(thisWindow){
            if(thisWindow.id != newWindow.id && thisWindow.id != closeLast){
                promises.push(removeWindow(thisWindow.id));
            }
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
            chrome.windows.remove(closeLast);
        });
    });
}

//creates a new window, and closes all the others
function closeAll(){
    chrome.windows.create({state: "maximized"}, closeOthers);
}
```

If I remove the `chrome.windows.remove(closeLast);` line, the specific window stays open as expected, and after closing it manually, it is reopened first after pressing Ctrl+Shift+T. Is there any way to achieve the same behaviour from the background script?

Comment: Try closing it in a separate event loop cycle - put the last `remove` inside setTimeout. Also try focusing it first.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I put it in a timeout of at least 100 ms it seems to work. Do you know if there is any reason why it doesn't work without it?

Comment: Evidently because that's how it's implemented in Chrome.